# How to use the same form DTO, with different validation annotations? How to avoid double code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

Which is the best practice to write DTO and follow different validated annotations, without double my code?
Below attached a simple example, that I want to avoid:

```
public class AddressForm1 {

    @NotEmpty
    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @Max(23)
    @Min(30)
    private BigDecimal lng;

    // getters & setters
}
```

and;

```
public class AddressForm2 {

    // removed annotation, empty value permitted
    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @Max(43)
    @Min(50)
    private BigDecimal lng;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validation group, and group your constraints. Than decide which set of constraints you'll apply using the *[@Validated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html)* annotation, with the appropriate group specified

Check the example in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/validation-groups-in-spring-mvc.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Groups, and validate some annotations only when you need, check this
[Group Hibernate Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups)