# Spring boot - Combine DTO and form validation

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-boot, dto

I am currently developing an API where I'm using DTO for the first time. So far I've used Spring's form validation with `javax.validation`.

So my question is if there is a way to combine both DTO and "form" validation. Let me explain myself: lets say I have a service to log in and another to register. In the service to register we have: name, password and email, the 3 of them must be filled. As for the login service, only the email and password must be filled. So we'd have something like:

```
private String name;
private String password;
private String email;
```

Until now, what I did was to create a POJO per request (forms) and then use annotations such as `@NotNull` but now with DTO in the project I'm in now they just have the same DTO and business object with the same properties and no constraints.

How could I do what I was usually doing? Checking the fields that must be not null in the controller looks a little dirty to me and I can't just put something like `@NotNull` in the `UserDTO` because then in the two examples I said I'd have to send also the `name` when logging in although it's not needed for that service.

So, how could I combine these 2 things? Is this something not possible or there's a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835122/how-to-use-the-same-form-dto-with-different-validation-annotations-how-to-avoi).

Comment: @AndrewS I think that's what I needed I think, what should I do now? delete this question? Idk what to do when repeated/related

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using two separate controllers for login and register requests.
And if it is the case, then you can make good use of org.springframework.validation.Validator interface:

```
@Component("registrationValidator")
public class RegistrationValidatorImpl implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> aClass) {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(final Object o, final Errors errors) {
    }
}
```

Create RegistrationValidatorImpl and LoginValidatorIml and @Autowire it in your controllers.

The usage of validator is simple:

```
invokeValidator(registrationValidator, someDTO, errors);

if (errors.hasErrors()) {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); //or whatever logic here
}
```

The controller method signature should be similar to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity register(@RequestBody final SomeDTO someDTO, final HttpServletRequest request, final Errors errors) {}
```

I case of one controller, I assume you have different methods mapped to login and register requests. You can @Autowire both validators in controller and use each in separate methods.

Comment: Hi, I am using the same controller for both since both are related to users

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using groups for validation with `javax.validation` did the work. I followed the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835122/how-to-use-the-same-form-dto-with-different-validation-annotations-how-to-avoi) question (as Andrew suggested), then I just had to put every field I wanted to have different rules in different groups.